# Identify image paint complete in browser

Tags: javascript, image

In case of a high resolution image load in browser, even after network got the image from server. Browser taking some time to display them as it paints gradually.

How can I identify this paint job is complete by browser?

http://postimg.org/image/txm6e94jz/ - check this image.

There image in home page is half rendered, what event can I use, to see that image rendered fully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to catch moment when image are rendered:

```js
function imageRenderedCallback() {
  alert("Image Rendered Callback executed");
};
function imageRenderingStarted() {
  requestAnimationFrame(imageRenderedCallback);
};

// Attach handler for load event. 
document.getElementById('my-image').addEventListener('load', function(){
  requestAnimationFrame(imageRenderingStarted);
});
```

```css
#my-image {
  width: 1680px;
  height: 1260px
}
```

```html
<body>
<img id="my-image" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/mount_fuji_japan_highest_mountain-">
</body>
```

See [**requestAnimationFrame. The secret to silky smooth JavaScript animation!**](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/) article with explanations of **what is** and **how to work with** *requestAnimationFrame*.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener for 'load' event.

```
document.getElementById('imgId').onload = function (){ /* image loaded */ }
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants to catch the rendering time too.

Comment: Image renders during loading, so event fires after image is rendered.

Comment: This seems not working. This helps me to identify image response came through network or not. But I need, after receiving image of very high resolution, browser paints the image in view gradually, does partial loadings and eventually completes. load is not helping for this case, to say this painting of image in browser is done or not.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/txm6e94jz/ - check this image. There image in home page is half rendered, what event can I use, to see that image rendered fully?

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to Andriy's solution but I found it a little more reliable... but way less clean. Gets the job done for me though.

```
// after preloading the image

requestAnimationFrame(function() {
   /*
   ... code to add the image to the dom
   */

   requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      document.body.offsetWidth // force repaint

      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
         // image is painted
      })
   })
})
```